# apt is broken relying on broken perl version

Tags: debian, perl, apt

while trying to upgrade packages on pibian I am running into the following issues, all issues to resolve it seem to involve upgrading perl which is not possible with apt relying on broken perl 
At this point all I think I can do is reinstall the OS

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ perl -version

This is perl 5, version 20, subversion 2 (v5.20.2) built for arm-    linux-gnueabihf-thread-multi-64int
(with 100 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

Copyright 1987-2015, Larry Wall

Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License     or the
GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.

Complete documentation for Perl, including FAQ lists, should be found on this system using "man perl" or "perldoc perl".  If you have access to the
Internet, point your browser at http://www.perl.org/, the Perl Home Page.

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get upgrade -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  bind9-host cpp-4.9 curl g++-4.9 gcc-4.9 gcc-4.9-base gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common libasan1 libatomic1 libavcodec56 libavformat56 libavresample2 libavutil54 libbind9-90 libcurl3 libcurl3-gnutls libdns-export100
  libdns100 libgcc-4.9-dev libgcc1 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgfortran3 libgomp1 libicu52 libirs-export91 libisc-export95 libisc95 libisccc90 libisccfg-export90 libisccfg90 liblwres90 libpoppler46 libstdc++-4.9-dev
  libstdc++6 libswscale3 libtiff5 libubsan0 libvorbis0a libvorbisenc2 libvorbisfile3 libxml2 plexmediaserver-installer poppler-utils rsync sensible-utils
48 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/41.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 38.9 kB disk space will be freed.
Reading changelogs... Done
debconf: Perl may be unconfigured (Can't locate strict.pm in @INC (you may need to install the strict module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl     /usr/local/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.20.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl5/5.20 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.20 /usr/share/perl/5.20 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at (eval 1) line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 1) line 2.
) -- aborting
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 conflicting diversions involving `/libpod-latex-perl' or `/usr/shave/maN/man1/Sh.1.gz'
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: First run `apt clean && apt update && apt upgrade` .

Comment: how did `strict.pm` get removed? If random files have been deleted then yes software will not work

Comment: im not sure how it was removed, its possible there was a failed/interrupted apt update previously